# How would I create a for-loop in Node.js

Tags: node.js, for-loop

I'm not very knowledged in node.js and i'm trying to create a for-loop, is there any way I can do this without it being super complex?

Comment: This is not the right place to ask about resources. But doing a for loop is javascript is easy... it does not have to do with node.js at all. [see](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_for_loop.htm)

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#1995:_JavaScript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let j=0,l=10; j<l; j++){
       console.log(j);
}
```

prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

but not 10